# I have a problem adding a text line after each woocommerce order in Advanced order export for woocommerce (CSV)

Tags: php, woocommerce, export-to-csv

I want to add a text row after each order (CSV).

I tried to tweak a code sample of adding an empty row but I think I'm missing the final step.

The text should show (after each order):

T-ORD + woocommerce order number + 50 empty characters + customer full name

Example expected export

```
BS-014242;BS-014242;1;09-09-2021;98703;8305;2;;"Menno Meester"
BS-014242;BS-014242;2;09-09-2021;98703;8308;1;;"Menno Meester"
T-ORDBS-014242                                ;Menno Meester
```

Code sample (empty row)

```
// add empty row after each order,   Excel/CSV/TAB formats
add_filter("woe_fetch_order_data", function($rows) {
    $rows[] = array("");
    return $rows;
});
```

My attempt:

```
// add text row with order number and customer full name after each order,   Excel/CSV/TAB formats
add_filter("woe_fetch_order_data", function($rows) {
    $rows[] = array("T-ORD", $order->get_order_number(), "                                                  ", $order->get_billing_full_name() );
    return $rows;
});
```

I am using the Advanced Order Export for Woocommerce plugin:
https://docs.algolplus.com/algol_order_export/format-output/

Does anyone know what I'm doing wrong? I look forward to your responde.

Kind regards,
Maico